# Зеркально простые числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, простые-числа

Решаю задачу с [e-olymp](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/22), ее текст:

*Назовем число "зеркально простым", если само число является простым, и простым является число, записанное теми же цифрами в обратном порядке.*

***Найти количество "зеркально простых" чисел на промежутке от a до b.***

*Входные данные:*

**Два числа a и b (1 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ 10000).**

*Выходные данные:*

**Вывести количество "зеркально простых" чисел на промежутке от a до b включительно.**

Однако при отправке решения из 15 проверок решение не проходит 3 из них, не могу понять в чем может быть проблема. Мой код:

```
start, end = map(int, input().split())


def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


n = 0

for i in range(start, end + 1):
    if is_prime(i) and is_prime(int(str(i)[::-1])):
        n += 1

print(n)
```

Comment: Кстати, код можно улучшить. Например, проверять делители только до квадратного корня из числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша программа считает единицу простым числом, хотя это не так. Добавьте недостающую проверку.

***Пример:***

```py
...
def is_prime(number):
    if number == 1:
        return False
...
```